# CMTimeGetSeconds returns 0 instead 0.0666667

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, cmtime

Hello I'm trying to convert an integer which represents a frame rate into CMTime to be able to set minFrameDuration in AVCaptureScreenInput.

Until now I have

```
int numberOfFrames = [self convertFrameRateStringToInt:[parameters objectForKey:@"frameRate"]];
Float64 frameDuration = 1.0/numberOfFrames;
NSLog(@"numberOfFrames %i - frameDuration %f",numberOfFrames, frameDuration);
NSLog(@"timeshow %f",CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(frameDuration, 1)));
return CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(frameDuration,1);
```

if the numberOfFrames is set to 15 frames per seconds then the frameDuration is 0.066667 therefore the parameters for CMTimeMakeWithSeconds are 0.066667 and 1 which means the CMTimeGetSeconds should return 0.066667/1 = 0.066667 but instead it returns 0.

Can some one figures out what I'm doing wrong and explain me why ?
Thanks.

Edit1: I made it to work changing the function like this :

```
int numberOfFrames = [self convertFrameRateStringToInt:string];
NSLog(@"timeshow %f",CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMake(1, (int32_t)numberOfFrames)));
return CMTimeMake(1, (int32_t)numberOfFrames);
```

I still can't understand why the last method didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be construction your `CMTime` like so:

```
CMTimeMake(1, numberOfFrames);
```

> A CMTime is represented as a rational number, with a numerator (an int64_t value), and a denominator (an int32_t timescale). Conceptually, the timescale specifies the fraction of a second each unit in the numerator occupies. Thus if the timescale is 4, each unit represents a quarter of a second; if the timescale is 10, each unit represents a tenth of a second, and so on.

Your call `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` adds `kCMTimeFlags_HasBeenRounded` to `CMTime`. Thats why it will round to the nearest full second.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah you have right it's working like this but can you explain why my method wasn't work

Comment: `NSLog(@"timeshow %f", CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeMake(1, numberOfFrames)));` outputs "timeshow 0.066667" for me. Thats the result you wanted.

Comment: I added the part about rounding to my answer

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't read well your answer I founded that solution by my self and I wanted to post it.

Comment: Thank you very much the CMTime object gave me an awful headake